# How do I catch an rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError in Python?

Tags: python, r, exception, runtime-error

**Setup:**

- Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2017, 12:15:08)
- Mac OSX 10.13.1

**Problem:**

I have downloaded the following R script https://github.com/daleroberts/heston/blob/master/heston.r
and I repeatedly call one of the functions in there via Python using the package RPy2. Now, for some of my inputs that I feed into the R function, R returns the following error:

> rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in integrate(PIntegrand, lower =
>   0, upper = Inf, lambda, vbar, eta,  :    roundoff error was detected

How do I go about catching this RuntimeError in Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `RRuntimeError` is derived from `Exception` so you should be able to catch it as you would with any other exception.

```
try:
    # your code
except rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError:
    # handle exception
```

---

**In rpy2 v3.0 and above**, `RRuntimeError` seems to have been moved elsewhere (see example code [from documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/introduction.html?highlight=rruntimeerror#graphics-and-plots)) so you may need to use this instead:

```
try:
    # your code
except rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError:
    # handle exception
```

---

More on this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: It may be under this path `rpy2.rinterface.embedded.RRuntimeError`

Comment: @wassname Yeah you're probably right, I might just remove references to the source code since it's always eventually going to be outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Python makes catching exceptions relatively easy.

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception, e:
    # Log the exception.
```

Comment: A RuntimeError is an exception in Python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the `rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError` to work, but the workaround below worked for me.

Installing `tryCatchLog`:

```
%%R
install.packages('tryCatchLog')
library('tryCatchLog')
```

If using it in a function:

```
def test_R_error_handling():
  %R tryCatchLog( expr = result <- 'a'+2, finally = result <- -1 )
  result = ro.globalenv['result'][0]
  if result == -1:
    print(result)
    return
  else:
    print('\nFunction continued')
    return True
```

This is on [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524327/catching-rpy2-runtime-errors) on rpy2 error handling. I hope this helps anyone experiencing the same issues.